# How to refactor a variable name in limited scope in Netbeans?

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, refactoring

I'm currently using NetBeans and want to rename all occurrence of a instance variable inside a method so that it will become a distinct local variable in its own right. I know how to refactor a variable using refactor -> rename, but I don't know how to limit the scope of change to a method.

Comment: Mark the method and use find&replace.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a local variable at the start of the method, then use the rename refactoring on it. Once done you can remove the local variable.